# Securely overwrite and erase a file in Python

Tags: python, file, security

I have been looking for a cost effective way to overwrite and remove a file in python (something like rm -P on macOS)

I have currently wrote something like

```
fileSize = os.path.getsize(filePath)
counter = 0 
  with open(filePath, 'w+') as file:
    while counter <= fileSize:
      file.write("0")
      counter+= 1
```

But come on.. .this is not good enough. I know in python we aren't able to get to a low level (ram) but I would like to implement something that is sufficiently better. I have heard that some people use `srm` to remove a file securely but that was back in 2013 and wondering if there is a better tool at this point.

If `srm` is still the lib to use, please send over an example on the best way to implement it.

Comment: `file.truncate()` in your loop I don't think that's going to work very well...

Comment: @jean Resolved Resolved, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python securely remove file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455300/python-securely-remove-file)