# How to add password to zip file

Tags: python

I use this script to make zipped backup of important folder but because after 5th backup files is moves to Recycle Bin and show to everyone I am looking for setpassword opinion to protect deleted zips or even better delete old zips but permanently (not move in Recycle Bin).

```
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import zipfile


OBJECT_TO_BACKUP = '/home/etre/test/'  # The file or directory to backup
BACKUP_DIRECTORY = '/home/etre/test-backup/'  # The location to store the backups in
MAX_BACKUP_AMOUNT = 5  # The maximum amount of backups to have in BACKUP_DIRECTORY


object_to_backup_path = Path(OBJECT_TO_BACKUP)
backup_directory_path = Path(BACKUP_DIRECTORY)
assert object_to_backup_path.exists()  # Validate the object we are about to backup exists before we continue

# Validate the backup directory exists and create if required
backup_directory_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

# Get the amount of past backup zips in the backup directory already
existing_backups = [
    x for x in backup_directory_path.iterdir()
    if x.is_file() and x.suffix == '.zip' and x.name.startswith('backup-')
]

# Enforce max backups and delete oldest if there will be too many after the new backup
oldest_to_newest_backup_by_name = list(sorted(existing_backups, key=lambda f: f.name))
while len(oldest_to_newest_backup_by_name) >= MAX_BACKUP_AMOUNT:  # >= because we will have another soon
    backup_to_delete = oldest_to_newest_backup_by_name.pop(0)
    backup_to_delete.unlink()

# Create zip file (for both file and folder options)
backup_file_name = f'backup-{datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}-{object_to_backup_path.name}.zip'
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(str(backup_directory_path / backup_file_name), mode='w')
if object_to_backup_path.is_file():
    # If the object to write is a file, write the file
    zip_file.write(
        object_to_backup_path.absolute(),
        arcname=object_to_backup_path.name,
        compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
    )
elif object_to_backup_path.is_dir():
    # If the object to write is a directory, write all the files
    for file in object_to_backup_path.glob('**/*'):
        if file.is_file():
            zip_file.write(
                file.absolute(),
                arcname=str(file.relative_to(object_to_backup_path)),
                compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
            )
# Close the created zip file
zip_file.close()
```

I tried this

```
`    zip_file.write(
        object_to_backup_path.absolute(),
        arcname=object_to_backup_path.name,
        compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
        setpassword(b'1234')
`
```

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a way to securely wipe or [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455300/python-securely-remove-file) a file.

Comment: Do you have a link to the docs for `zipfile` module or method `setpassword` ? See also [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250/how-to-create-an-encrypted-zip-file)

Answer (score 0):

Official Python Zip File documentation is available [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)

the following code useful:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import zipfile

myzip = ZipFile('test.zip') 
myzip.setpassword(b"asasasasasas")
myzip.extract(member='Roughwork/pretify.html',pwd=b"asasasasasas")
```

**Syntax**:

```
ZipFile.extract(member, file_path=None , pwd=None)
```

**Parameters**:

**members**: It specifies the name of files to be extracted.

**file_path**: location where archive file needs to be extracted, if file_path is None then contents of zip file will be extracted to the current working directory

**pwd**: the password used for encrypted files, By default pwd is None.

[useful link..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195747/code-to-create-a-password-encrypted-zip-file)