# An up to date Python function for deleting files securely?

Tags: python, file, security

I am trying to write an up to date **Python** function for removing files **securely**. This quest led me to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455300/python-securely-remove-file#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20srm%20to,()%20function%20to%20call%20srm.), the answers to which, as I understand it, give me two options:

1. Install the `srm` command, and call that using `subprocess` or something similar.
2. Use a given custom function.

I have to reject option (1) because, although I am using Linux myself, I am writing code destined for a custom PIP package, which needs to be as lightweight and portable as possible.

As for option (2): I have distilled the various functions supplied in the answers to the aforementioned question into one function:

```py
def secure_delete(path_to_file, passes=1):
    length = os.path.getsize(path_to_file)
    with open(path, "br+", buffering=-1) as file_to_overwrite:
        for _ in range(passes):
            file_to_overwrite.seek(0)
            file_to_overwrite.write(os.urandom(length))
    os.remove(path_to_file)
```

Now this looks like we could be getting somewhere, but I still have some queries:

- I believe that the `os.path` stuff has largely been superceded by `pathlib`. Is that correct?
- But what about that `os.urandom(length)` call? Is that the most efficient, up to date way of doing that?
- I understand what that `passes` variable is doing, but I do not understand what the point of it is. Is there really all the much to be gain, from a security point of view, by overwriting multiple times?

Comment: It was (still is?) the case that writing was though to leave a ghost of the prior value so secure delete tools would overwrite the file contents several times.

Comment: _Is there much gained by overwriting multiple times_ For certain kinds of physical storage mediums (e.g. magnetic platters), yes.  For other kinds, perhaps not.

Comment: `os.path` vs. `pathlib`: I wouldn't ding somebody for not using `pathlib`, especially here where you're not using any of its extra functionality.

`os.urandom`: since Python 3.6, there's the `secrets` module that gives you an interface to the best-available random number source.

Number of passes: more is probably better, but as always "what's your threat model?" Are you trying to prevent your roommate from reading the deleted data, or a global superpower?

`srm` also renames the file to something random and truncates it to 0 bytes

Comment: @bbayles If you were inclined to expand that comment into an answer, and if you could spell out explicitly what the `secrets` equivalent to `os.urandom` is - in the context of the code in the question, at least - then I would happily give it the green tick of acceptance. (I am already using `secrets` in another part of the same file, so using `secrets` would dovetail really nicely with the rest of the code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pathlib` equivalent of `os.path.getsize(path_to_file)` would be  `Path(path_to_file).stat().st_size`. I think the `os.path` version is cleaner and would use it unless I needed something else from `pathlib`.

---

The `secrets` module ought to be used any time you're not sure about the best way to do something with random numbers.

`secrets.SystemRandom().randbytes(n)` will give you the best available set of `n` random bytes. Under the hood it uses `os.urandom`.

---

Overwriting a file's contents multiple times theoretically impairs forensic recovery methods from retrieving them, but how much extra safety it buys you depends on various factors.

[Wei et al 2011](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/fast11/tech/full_papers/Wei.pdf) found some amount leftover data even using schemes with dozens of overwrite passes.

Comment: *Overwriting a file's contents multiple times theoretically impairs forensic recovery methods from retrieving them*  Beware copy-on-write filesystems, where it does nothing because it won't actually overwrite the data.